# Import assertion throwing mime type error

Tags: javascript, import

I'm trying to dynamically import a json file like:

```
let filePath = "../../mapping_data_files/contactMapping.json";
import(filePath, {
        assert: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }).then(file => {
        console.log(file);
});
```

But as I add the assertion i get the error:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

How can I work around it?

If I remove the assert I get
`Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'}` instead of the content of my json file.

Comment: I think you are using old version of node, min version seems [17.1.0 or v16.14.0](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-assertions). Also note that JSON module is still [experimental, stability 1](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules)  so use `fs.promises.readFile` along with `json.parse` instead.

Comment: @bogdanoff My node version actually is 17.4.0 so this should work.

Comment: @temp Are you using the `--experimental-json-modules` flag? The [compatibility table](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility) says that `{ type: "json" }` is only fully supported starting from Node 17.5.0.

Comment: @SebastianSimon No, i don't. I guess I'll just look for a different method of conditionally import.

Comment: @temp Well, your two alternatives would be to pass that flag when running Node or just upgrade Node.

Comment: @SebastianSimon All right. If you could post an answer I'd accept it.